# Separate src and test directories with Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, class, visual-studio-code, python-import

I am getting a compilation error on the `from` line in the test file when I place my test and src files in different subfolders: `"Unable to import 'classA' pylint(import-error)`. It was working when the src and test files were in the same directory. This makes me think it's something to do with the settings.json file, but I'm not sure. Any ideas on how to fix it?

```
repo
├── .vscode
│   └── settings.json
├── src
│   ├── classA.py
│   └── classB.py
└── tests
     ├── classA_test.py
     └── classB_test.py
```

classA.py:

```
from datetime import date

class fetchData():
    var = ""

    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.var = thing

    def getInfo(self, x):
        ..process things..
        return info
```

classA_test.py

```
import unittest
from classA import fetchData

class classA(unittest.TestCase):
    def testStuff(self):
        ..testStuff..
```

settings.json

```
{
    "python.testing.unittestArgs": [
        "-v",
        "-s",
        "./tests",
        "-p",
        "*_test.py"
    ],
    "python.testing.pytestEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.nosetestsEnabled": false,
    "python.testing.unittestEnabled": true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct format is as follows:

```
repo
├── .vscode
│   ├── settings.json
├── src
│   ├── classA.py
│   └── classB.py
└── tests
     ├── __init__.py     (empty file)
     ├── classA_test.py
     └── classB_test.py
```

classA_test.py

```
import unittest
from src.classA import fetchData

class classA(unittest.TestCase):
    def testStuff(self):
        ..testStuff..
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this [link](https://gist.github.com/tasdikrahman/2bdb3fb31136a3768fac)

You can do something like this in your test:

```
# import the package
import antigravity

# import the antigravity module
from antigravity import antigravity

# or an object inside the antigravity module
from antigravity.antigravity import my_object
```

But make sure that you added `__init__.py` files in each directory to make it a package (you can leave them empty)

Hope that works.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I'm still getting the same issue :(

Comment: I think that doing `from src.classA import *` for example should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: This used to work for me a few months ago, but it doesn't anymore. Something has changed, but I don't know what.